# DataTables - I don't want the search/filter and length options on some tables

Tags: datatables

How do I initialise specific tables without the search filter and length select menu?

Apparently it can be done with the sDom option, but the documentation is pretty bad and I can't understand exactly what I am supposed to do.

http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can set to false such properties during initialization of datatable:

```
"bFilter" : false,               
"bLengthChange": false
```

Comment: Matt you are completely wrong. Adding `"lengthMenu": [[...], [....]]` and changing the value on this parameter you can show as much as item you want. Like you can show 20 or 30 item programmatically and also the label show and drop down box (which normally appear if u don't use `"bLengthChange": false`) will disappear.

Answer (score 22):

Since **Datatables 1.10** you can use those 2 options :

- [lengthChange](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange)

  `"lengthChange": false`
- [searching](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching)

  `"searching": false`

**Full example :**

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "lengthChange": false,
  "searching": false
} );
```

Answer (score 5):

Without search filter and length

```
var options = {"sDom": 'rtip'}
var myDataTable = $('#myDataTable')  
myDataTable.dataTable(options)
```

Here is an example from the official documentation: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html

Answer (score 3):

I agree that sDom is tricky, I got the hang of it by practicing. Run the example below and see the "info" will appear in the top.  Replace sDom with "sDom": 'rtlp' and see info disappear.  Now use "sDom": 'rtil' and see info is back at the bottom, but paging is gone.  Keep experimenting and you will get it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <link href="demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<table class="display dataTable" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "aaData": [
                [ "Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", 4, "X" ],
                [ "Gecko", "Firefox 3", "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+", 1.9, "A" ],
                [ "Webkit", "Safari 3.0", "OSX.4+", 522.1, "A" ]
            ],
            "sDom": '<"top"i>rtlp'
        } ); 
    } );
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```